# « des médias » ou « des média » ?

Tags: orthographe, pluriel, latin

Doit-on écrire « des médias » ou « des média » ?

Google fight :

- *des médias*: 20 900 000 résultats
- *des média*: 1 180 000 résultats

Ce [blog post](http://nekid.fr/2010/03/01/un-media-des-medias/) supporte le *s*. Dans Wikipédia on trouve des articles qui contiennent les deux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le fait même d'écrire *média* (et non *media*) oblige à toute fin pratique d'utiliser le pluriel français. De toute façon, *médium* ne s'emploie pas comme le singulier de ce mot...

De Villers (Multidictionnaire, 4e éd.) et Grevisse (14e éd., §535 b., qui ne cite même pas *média* comme pluriel invariable, usage qui est à mon avis un anglicisme doublement mal placé) sont d'accord sur ce point.

Comment: Libération a une rubrique **Médias** sur son site. Je n'ai entendu "L'utilisation de ce [nouveau] *médium* ..." qu'au temps des disquettes souples 5,25 pouces, des terminaux en mode caractères ; temps que les moins de vingt ans ....

Comment: @cl-r Doit dépendre du milieu : moi je l'entends souvent.

Comment: Donc "un médium, des médias" si je comprends bien ta réponse ?

Comment: Non. Dans le sens journalistique, "un média, des médias", sinon "un médium, des médiums".

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit ici d'une faute d'orthographe tellement courante qu'elle est devenue la règle. Au départ, dans les dictionnaires français on considérait comme juste l'usage des mots « medium » au singulier et « media » au pluriel. Ensuite « les médias » a été tellement utilisé que le singulier « média » est même apparu !

Aujourd'hui, entre Le Larousse et Le Robert, seul le Larousse cautionne encore l'ancien usage. Ainsi on peut lire dans Le Larousse en ligne (consulté le 2/8/2023) : [On trouve aussi *médium* ou *medium* au singulier, et *media*, nom masculin invariable.]

Comment: Les singulier *medium* et pluriel *media* sont l'usage du latin, celui qu'on respecte quand on écrit ces mots en italiques mais si on écrit en français, on met logiquement un accent à média pour préserver la prononciation, et si une nouvelle acception anglaise est adoptée (via *mass media* généralement au singulier comme au pluriel en anglais), la logique du français conduit à y ajouter un *S* au pluriel. Est-ce que tu considères *un spaghetti* et *des spaghettis* comme des fautes d'orthographe ?